# Простой способ получить кадр или серию кадров с Веб-Камеры?

Tags: web-camera, delphi, изображения, c++

Простой способ получить кадр или серию кадров с Веб-Камеры?
Что-то типа функции с заданными параметрами.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Uses
  ... , ShellAPI
const
WM_CAP_START = WM_USER;
WM_CAP_STOP = WM_CAP_START + 68;
WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = WM_CAP_START + 10;
WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = WM_CAP_START + 11;
WM_CAP_SAVEDIB = WM_CAP_START + 25;
WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME = WM_CAP_START + 60;
WM_CAP_SEQUENCE = WM_CAP_START + 62;
WM_CAP_FILE_SET_CAPTURE_FILEA = WM_CAP_START + 20;

function capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszWindowName : PCHAR;
dwStyle : longint;
x : integer;
y : integer;
nWidth : integer;
nHeight : integer;
ParentWin : HWND;
nId : integer): HWND; stdcall external 'AVICAP32.DLL';

var hWndC : THandle;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 hWndC := capCreateCaptureWindowA('My Own Capture Window',
WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE ,
0,
0,
Panel1.Width,
Panel1.Height,
Panel1.Handle,
0); //создаем область для вывода получаемых в будущем картинок =)

if hWndC <> 0 then //если при создании области ошибок не возникло, то сопкойно начинаем забирать данный с веб-камеры
    SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0);  //забираем картинку с вебкамеры

end;
```

Это самый простой вариант получения одного кадра, для серии используйте таймер.

Но лучше использовать сразу **DirectX** ,а точнее надстройку для Delphi **DSPack** примеров в сети море

Comment: и это простой способ?
кстати, я его ранее пробовал,и он мне не подходит.

Comment: да это самый простой способ, если не подходит значит камер имеет не стандартный вывод, тогда только **DSPack**, но там кода еще больше писать портянку лень.

Comment: ИМХО, более простой способ - OpenCV. Стена кода сведется до пары строчек.

Comment: @Nofate у какждого своё понимание простоты ;)

Comment: Да не спорю. тут либо тащить зависимости, но пара строчек, либо стандартными средствами, но побольше кода. Кому что проще.

Comment: ну в случае с **DSPACK** установил компонент , бросил на форму 3 компонента и получай.Только Внимательно нужно прочитать инструкцию по установке, а то не читая ставят а оно не ставится.